# Issue Loop Tesseract and Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying make a loop tessract and opencv to recognize a operation. But when run through some times then opencv still give out normal images and  tessract dont run normal (output incorrect).**This issue just really happened when i run it with multi images**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjwD.png)

Comment: show us the code you run.

Answer (score 0):

```
with mss.mss() as sct:
        # Grab the data
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)

        # Save to the picture file
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=path)

    # load the image 
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='bot')
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=False,default=path,help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", type=str, default="thresh", help="type of preprocessing to be done")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    # load the image 
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if args["preprocess"] == "thresh":
        gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# make a check to see if median blurring should be done to remove
# noise
    elif args["preprocess"] == "blur":
        gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)

# write the grayscale image to disk as a temporary file so we can
# apply OCR to it
    filename = ("Scripts/Screens/" +str(i) +".png").format(os.getpid())
    cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename),config='--psm 7', lang ="eng+equ")
```

I m so sorry about that